# Debuggee not connected message when using windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am trying to debug my application but when I start windbg with the following

windbg.exe -g myapp.exe

Windbg says "Debuggee not connected". Then I have to manually breaking and hit go. Then I see "windbg is running."

I have to launch multiple windbg sessions so hitting break + go on each session is not my option. I also have to use -g and -G.

Is something setup incorrectly with my windbg?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That message is benign and as expected, you won't get the other message until you go through your first break/resume cycle. It doesn't indicate that anything is wrong.

-scott

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation scott.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to debug an application by ignoring the Initial break-point?

I was able to do the same with this

```
windbg -g c:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Yes I am. I see the same not connected message.